# How to filter using GA API in Google Sheets

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters, referrer-spam

How do I exclude referrals from a specific URL using the GA API in Google Sheets?

I have tried [ ga:referralPath!= ] in the Filters row

I have tried [ sessions::condition::ga:referralPath!= ] in the Segments row

However, I cannot make it match the filtered data in Google Analytics.

Here's what I did in Google Analytics: new segment > condition > filter > sessions > exclude > referral path > contains > URL

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong in Google Sheets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what kind of referal you want to block, but you might need to exclude: ga:source.. don't forget to add ga:source also as a dimension otherwise it doesn't work. Which could have been the same reason your ga:referralPath! didn't work